# Recyclerview not scrolling after overlay view is removed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have the following layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">     

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/horizontal_rcv"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="90dp"
       android:alpha="1.0"
       android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16"/>

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/vertical_rcv"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:alpha="0.0"
       android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Based on an event I make the vertical recycler view visible and gone.

Problem:
Horizontal recyclerview stops smooth scrolling as soon as the following is performed. Horizontal scroll view alpha is changed from 1 - 0 - 1 and vertical rcv goes from GONE - VISIBLE - GONE.

I still get the touch event for horizontal rcv in onInterceptTouchEvent by adding addOnItemTouchListener but the scrolling seems to stutter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Arent those 2 RecyclerView's overlaping?? you have android:layout_height="90dp" on one and android:layout_height="match_parent" on the other. Maybe its better if your wrap it in a Framelayout. Anyway have you tried setting height to 0dp instead of view gone. I never tried it personally but may work

Comment: They are supposed to overlap and at a time only one is supposed to be visible. How is FrameLayout going to help?

Comment: With a FrameLayout it will Overlap without interfering with the view beneath it. Ty that and set the height to 0dp for the view that Need to go instead of View GONE.  See if that doesnt mess with the scrolling

Comment: FrameLayout did not work but but but the trick of changing height worked. Thanks a ton! You might want to create answer and I would accept it.

Comment: Cool. I mentioned FrameLayout because of the overlap. Ill create an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comments,

Instead of View Gone set the height to 0dp instead